# Future <List<Bluetooth>> service not updating widget tree

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a stateful widget below that runs an async function on startup to connect to a BLE device and subsequently await discovery of the bluetooth services.

My Future builder does not update the widget tree to display the contents of _services once it is finished. I know I need to use setState() somewhere to force a widget tree update but I can't figure out how.

Any help would be great thank you!

```
import 'package:flutter_blue/flutter_blue.dart';

class DeviceView extends StatefulWidget {
  const DeviceView({Key? key, required this.device}) : super(key: key);

  final BluetoothDevice device;

  @override
  _DeviceViewState createState() => _DeviceViewState();
}

class _DeviceViewState extends State<DeviceView> {
  Future<List<BluetoothService>> _services;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _services = _getServices();
  }
 
  Future<List<BluetoothService>> _getServices() async {
    try {
      await widget.device.connect();
    } catch (e) {
      if (e.hashCode.toString() != 'already_connected') {
        throw e;
      }
    }
    return widget.device.discoverServices();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    widget.device.disconnect();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF004EFF),
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              _services == null
                  ? Text('No Services Yet...')
                  : FutureBuilder<List<BluetoothService>>(
                      future: _services,
                      builder: (c, snapshot) => Text(snapshot.data.toString())),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the correct way of doing this but I seem to have found a solution:

By calling the getServices() async function directly in init state and then using it again directly in the future builder the widget tree now updates when the discoverServices() completes its scan...

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getServices();
  }
```

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF004EFF),
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              _getServices().hashCode.toString() == ''
                  ? Text('No Services Yet...')
                  : FutureBuilder<List<BluetoothService>>(
                      future: _getServices(),
                      builder: (c, snapshot) => Text(snapshot.data.toString())),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your code at this line:

```
future: _services,
```

_services is not a Future. Please change its type to Future and in initState assign it like:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _services = _getServices();
}
```

**EDIT** In case the _getServices resolves too quickly(not heavy in processing) you may call it directly in

```
future: _getServices()
```

Comment: Thanks, this has been corrected.
Although this hasn't solved the core question of how to go about enforcing a widget tree reload on completion of the await asynchronous function getServices(). 

Any thoughts?

Comment: @DarioS I made an edit. Saw your solution and it it looks correct. One note: most probably you do not need to call _getServices() in initState. It is pointless but cannot say for sure without seeing native implementation of bluetooth package you are using.

Comment: Great! Thanks fo the help Eduard. I have removed the _getServices() from initState